# Making filled circles in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

How can you make filled-in circles in cocos2d? I understand you have to create a new method, but I don't really understand how it works/how to do it. Could someone please provide maybe an example or tell me how to go about achieving this? Also, I need to create about 24 filled-in circles, would this cause lags of some sort? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "***I understand you have to create a new method, but I don't really understand how it works/how to do it.***" but I can tell you how to create a filled circle in cocos2d.

All you need is an image of circle of any color that you want or a white one if you want to change the color of the circle in your game.

With these circles as sprites in the game, the lags should not occur as I have a game that has 70-80 sprites in a game(A Cards game) and it never lagged even when i played pretty complicated animation in the game.

Comment: Thanks for the sprite idea. I add the circles to the screen in a for loop however, using the ccDrawCircle function inside the draw method. How can I add the 24 circles onto the screen fast and easily?

Comment: @Seany242 Use sprites, it's going to be faster and easier than drawing filled circles with only OpenGL (eg. without a sprite texture).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but @bummzack is right, using a sprite is simple and will be fasted due to cocos2d texture cache.

Comment: how would i change the color of the circle during the game if I import a white sprite?

Comment: Set the tint color of the image, that should take care of it.